# can not link the add button to table view controller - Xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios4, xcode4, xcode4.3

I need to link the add button from table list view controller to add view controller but the link is cannot created , when i click the add button its move to the another control cannot to be link in xocde

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of ctrl-dragging from the graphical representation of your button, ctrl-drag from the list of controls.

E.g., in the picture below, you can ctrl-drag from "Button - Show Label" on to your view controller.

[image]

Comment: you sir have understood the contents of the post, that alone deserves a +